# SQL: Grouping entries by one colum, regardless of the values of other colums

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to group entries in a table by just one matching colum. Here is an example of the data:

```
COLUM1       COLUM2       COLUM3
034          XY           CV
040          FG           RR
098          GT           ZT
034          CC           UU
034          ZT           HG
098          QA           BN
```

Now I want to group this data just by COLUM1, regardless of the values in the other colums. So that the output looks like this:

```
COLUM1       COLUM2       COLUM3
034          XY           CV
034          ZT           HG
034          CC           UU
098          QA           BN
098          GT           ZT
040          FG           RR
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Simply ORDER BY COLUM1?

Comment: Your output just looks like you have ordered it? is there more data your not showing, or do you mean order by?

Comment: Or do you mean order by the amount of entry's? e.g. 3 x 34, 2 x 98, 1 x 40 ?

Comment: I already thought of order by, but I would not want them to be exactly ordered. I thought there my be another solution i did not think of yet

Comment: What is the logic to the order you want

Comment: I will try to implement it with an Order By and see if this is applicable for the application in the front end. I will get back to you then

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT COLUM1, COLUM2, COLUM3
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY COLUM1
```

Answer (score -1):

Simlpy use

```
order by column1;
```

But if you want to use group by and order by in same query you can use

```
select * from (
select * from table1 order by column1) tempName
group by calumn2;
```

Its not efficient but its working.